# Restangular set default headers error

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm new with Restangular and I need to send an access token to the server on every request.

I'm trying

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'access_token': 'token'});
```

But I'm getting Bad-Request error from my server.

I'm testing my rest Api with RestClient in firefox and is working fine.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a restangular error? I tried your exact restangular line & it sends the header just fine. Could you elaborate on what happens server side?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My error was that in my server I forgot to add "access_token" header into Allow-Headers response.